# React Error: cannot read cars.map() function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I create MERN stack app and now I want to add Search and filters functions. I created SearchScreen.js and in carRoutes.js added carRouter.get with '/search' query. But the browser said me Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') . That is in SearchSreen.js in 'cars.map' row. Can you help me ?

I show the code:

**SearchScreen.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { getError } from '../utils';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Car from '../components/Car';
import LinkContainer from 'react-router-bootstrap/LinkContainer';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        cars: action.payload.cars,
        page: action.payload.page,
        pages: action.payload.pages,
        countCars: action.payload.countCars,
        loading: false,
      };
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const prices = [
  {
    name: '$1 to $50',
    value: '1-50',
  },
  {
    name: '$51 to $80',
    value: '51-80',
  },
  {
    name: '$80 to $160',
    value: '80-160',
  },
];

export const ratings = [
  {
    name: '4stars & up',
    rating: 4,
  },

  {
    name: '3stars & up',
    rating: 3,
  },

  {
    name: '2stars & up',
    rating: 2,
  },

  {
    name: '1stars & up',
    rating: 1,
  },
];

export default function SearchScreen() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const sp = new URLSearchParams(search); // /search?category=Jeep
  const category = sp.get('category') || 'all';
  const query = sp.get('query') || 'all';
  const pricePerHour = sp.get('price Per Hour') || 'all';
  const rating = sp.get('rating') || 'all';
  const order = sp.get('order') || 'newest';
  const page = sp.get('page') || 1;

  const [{ loading, error, cars, pages, countCars }, dispatch] =
    useReducer(reducer, {
      loading: true,
      error: '',
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `/api/cars/search?page=${page}&query=${query}&category=${category}&price=${pricePerHour}&rating=${rating}&order=${order}`
        );
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_FAIL',
          payload: getError(error),
        });
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [category, error, order, page, pricePerHour, query, rating]);

  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCategories = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/cars/categories`);
        setCategories(data);
      } catch (err) {
        toast.error(getError(err));
      }
    };
    fetchCategories();
  }, [dispatch]);

  const getFilterUrl = (filter, skipPathname) => {
    const filterPage = filter.page || page;
    const filterCategory = filter.category || category;
    const filterQuery = filter.query || query;
    const filterRating = filter.rating || rating;
    const filterPricePerHour = filter.price || pricePerHour;
    const sortOrder = filter.order || order;
    return `${
      skipPathname ? '' : '/search?'
    }category=${filterCategory}&query=${filterQuery}&price=${filterPricePerHour}&rating=${filterRating}&order=${sortOrder}&page=${filterPage}`;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Search Products</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Row>
        <Col md={3}>
          <h3>Department</h3>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link
                  className={'all' === category ? 'text-bold' : ''}
                  to={getFilterUrl({ category: 'all' })}
                >
                  Any
                </Link>
              </li>
              {categories.map((c) => (
                <li key={c}>
                  <Link
                    className={c === category ? 'text-bold' : ''}
                    to={getFilterUrl({ category: c })}
                  >
                    {c}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Price</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link
                  className={'all' === pricePerHour ? 'text-bold' : ''}
                  to={getFilterUrl({ price: 'all' })}
                >
                  Any
                </Link>
              </li>
              {prices.map((p) => (
                <li key={p.value}>
                  <Link
                    to={getFilterUrl({ pricePerHour: p.value })}
                    className={p.value === pricePerHour ? 'text-bold' : ''}
                  >
                    {p.name}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Avg. Customer Review</h3>
            <ul>
              {ratings.map((r) => (
                <li key={r.name}>
                  <Link
                    to={getFilterUrl({ rating: r.rating })}
                    className={`${r.rating}` === `${rating}` ? 'text-bold' : ''}
                  >
                    <Rating caption={' & up'} rating={r.rating}></Rating>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
              <li>
                <Link
                  to={getFilterUrl({ rating: 'all' })}
                  className={rating === 'all' ? 'text-bold' : ''}
                >
                  <Rating caption={' & up'} rating={0}></Rating>
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col md={9}>
          {loading ? (
            <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
          ) : error ? (
            <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Row className="justify-content-between mb-3">
                <Col md={6}>
                  <div>
                    {countCars === 0 ? 'No' : countCars} Results
                    {query !== 'all' && ' : ' + query}
                    {category !== 'all' && ' : ' + category}
                    {pricePerHour !== 'all' && ' : Price ' + pricePerHour}
                    {rating !== 'all' && ' : Rating ' + rating + ' & up'}
                    {query !== 'all' ||
                    category !== 'all' ||
                    rating !== 'all' ||
                    pricePerHour !== 'all' ? (
                      <Button
                        variant="light"
                        onClick={() => navigate('/search')}
                      >
                        <i className="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
                      </Button>
                    ) : null}
                  </div>
                </Col>
                <Col className="text-end">
                  Sort by{' '}
                  <select
                    value={order}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      navigate(getFilterUrl({ order: e.target.value }));
                    }}
                  >
                    <option value="newest">Newest Arrivals</option>
                    <option value="lowest">Price: Low to High</option>
                    <option value="highest">Price: High to Low</option>
                    <option value="toprated">Avg. Customer Reviews</option>
                  </select>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              {cars?.length === 0 && (
                <MessageBox>No Product Found</MessageBox>
              )}

              <Row>
                {cars.map((car) => (
                  <Col sm={6} lg={4} className="mb-3" key={car._id}>
                    <Car car={car}></Car>
                  </Col>
                ))}
              </Row>

              <div>
                {[...Array(pages).keys()].map((x) => (
                  <LinkContainer
                    key={x + 1}
                    className="mx-1"
                    to={{
                      pathname: '/search',
                      seacrh: getFilterUrl({ page: x + 1 }, true),
                    }}
                  >
                    <Button
                      className={Number(page) === x + 1 ? 'text-bold' : ''}
                      variant="light"
                    >
                      {x + 1}
                    </Button>
                  </LinkContainer>
                ))}
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**carRoutes.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import Car from '../models/carModel.js';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import { isAuth, isAdmin } from '../utils.js';

const carRouter = express.Router();

carRouter.get('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const cars = await Car.find();
    res.send(cars);
});


carRouter.get('/search',expressAsyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{
  const {query} = req;
  const pageSize = query.pageSize || PAGE_SIZE;
  const page = query.page || 1;
  const category = query.category || '';
  const pricePerHour = query.pricePerHour || '';
  const rating = query.rating || '';
  const order = query.order || '';
  const searchQuery = query.query || '';
  

  const queryFilter =
        searchQuery && searchQuery !== 'all'
          ? {
              name: {
                $regex: searchQuery,
                $options: 'i',
              },
            }
          : {};
      const categoryFilter = category && category !== 'all' ? { category } : {};
      const ratingFilter =
        rating && rating !== 'all'
          ? {
              rating: {
                $gte: Number(rating),
              },
            }
          : {};
      const priceFilter =
        pricePerHour && pricePerHour !== 'all'
          ? {
              // 1-50
              pricePerHour: {
                $gte: Number(pricePerHour.split('-')[0]),
                $lte: Number(pricePerHour.split('-')[1]),
              },
            }
          : {};
      const sortOrder =
        order === 'featured'
          ? { featured: -1 }
          : order === 'lowest'
          ? { pricePerHour: 1 }
          : order === 'highest'
          ? { pricePerHour: -1 }
          : order === 'toprated'
          ? { rating: -1 }
          : order === 'newest'
          ? { createdAt: -1 }
          : { _id: -1 };

      const cars = await Car.find({
        ...queryFilter,
        ...categoryFilter,
        ...priceFilter,
        ...ratingFilter,
      })
        .sort(sortOrder)
        .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
        .limit(pageSize);

      const countCars = await Car.countDocuments({
        ...queryFilter,
        ...categoryFilter,
        ...priceFilter,
        ...ratingFilter,
      });
      res.send({
        cars,
        countCars,
        page,
        pages: Math.ceil(countCars / pageSize),
      });
    })
  );

carRouter.post('/', isAuth, expressAsyncHandler(async (req,res)=> {
  const newCar = new Car({
        mark: 'sample-name' + Date.now() ,
        model: 'sample-name' + Date.now(),
        year: 0,
        category: 'sample-category',
        capacity: 0,
        fuelType: 'sample-name',
        transmission: 'sample-name',
        image: 'sample-image',
        pricePerHour: 0,
        pricePerDay: 0,
        available: true,
        description: 'sample description',
  });
  const car = await newCar.save();
  res.send({message: 'Car created', car});
})
);


  carRouter.put(
        '/:id',
        isAuth,
        expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
          const carId = req.params.id;
          const car = await Car.findById(carId);
          if (car) {
            car.mark = req.body.mark;
            car.model = req.body.model;
            car.year = req.body.year;
            car.capacity = req.body.capacity;
            car.fuelType = req.body.fuelType;
            car.transmission = req.body.transmission;
            car.pricePerDay = req.body.pricePerDay;
            car.pricePerHour = req.body.pricePerHour;
            car.image = req.body.image;
            car.category = req.body.category;
            car.available = req.body.available;
            car.description = req.body.description;
            await car.save();
            res.send({ message: 'Car Updated' });
          } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'Car Not Found' });
          }
        })
      );

  carRouter.delete(
        '/:id',
        isAuth,
        expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
          const car = await Car.findById(req.params.id);
          if (car) {
            await car.deleteOne();
            res.send({ message: 'Car Deleted' });
          } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'Car Not Found' });
          }
        })
      );


      carRouter.post(
        '/:id/reviews',
        isAuth,
        expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
          const carId = req.params.id;
          const car = await Car.findById(carId);
          if (car) {
            if (car.reviews.find((x) => x.name === req.user.name)) {
              return res
                .status(400)
                .send({ message: 'You already submitted a review' });
            }
      
            const review = {
              name: req.user.name,
              rating: Number(req.body.rating),
              comment: req.body.comment,
            };
            car.reviews.push(review);
            car.numReviews = car.reviews.length;
            car.rating =
              car.reviews.reduce((a, c) => c.rating + a, 0) /
              car.reviews.length;
            const updatedCar = await car.save();
            res.status(201).send({
              message: 'Review Created',
              review: updatedCar.reviews[updatedCar.reviews.length - 1],
              numReviews: car.numReviews,
              rating: car.rating,
            });
          } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'Car is Not Found' });
          }
        })
      );

const PAGE_SIZE = 3;

carRouter.get(
    '/admin',
    isAuth , expressAsyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{
        const {query} = req;
        const page = query.page || 1 ;
        const pageSize = query.pageSize || PAGE_SIZE;

        const cars = await Car.find()
        .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
        .limit(pageSize);
        const countCars = await Car.countDocuments();
        res.send({
            cars,
            countCars,
            page,
            pages: Math.ceil(countCars / pageSize),
        })
    })
)

carRouter.get('/model/:model', async (req,res)=>{
    const car = await Car.findOne({model: req.params.model});
    if(car){
        res.send(car);
    }else{
        res.status(404).send({message: 'Car Not Found'});
    }
});

carRouter.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const car = await Car.findById(req.params.id);
  if (car) {
    res.send(car);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ message: 'Car Not Found' });
  }
});


export default carRouter;
```

**carModel.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        comment: {type: String, required:true},
        rating: {type: Number, required: true},
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

const carSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        mark: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        model: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        year: {type: Number, required: true},
        category: {type: String, required: true},
        capacity: {type: Number, required:true},
        fuelType: {type: String, required: true},
        transmission: {type: String, required: true},
        image: {type: String, required: true},
        pricePerHour: {type: Number, required: true},
        pricePerDay: {type: Number, required: true},
        available: {type: Boolean},
        location: {
            lat: Number,
            lng: Number,
            address: String,
            name: String,
            vicinity: String,
            googleAddressId: String
        },
        rating: {type: Number},
        numReviews: {type: Number},
        description: {type: String, required: true},
        reviews: [reviewSchema]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

const Car = mongoose.model('Car',carSchema);
export default Car;
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide complete and valid initial state to the `useReducer` hook. If you are expecting to be able to destructure `loading`, `error`, `cars`, `pages`, and `countCars` from the reducer hook's state, then the initial state should include all these values.

Example:

```js
useReducer(reducer, {
  cars: [],
  countCars: 0,
  error: '',
  loading: true,
  pages: [],
});
```

This way on the initial render cycle before data requests are made, the UI has defined state to render from.

```
const [{ loading, error, cars, pages, countCars }, dispatch] = useReducer(
  reducer,
  {
    cars: [],
    countCars: 0,
    error: '',
    loading: true,
    pages: [],
  }
);

...

<Row>
  {cars.map((car) => (
    <Col sm={6} lg={4} className="mb-3" key={car._id}>
      <Car car={car} />
    </Col>
  ))}
</Row>
...
```

Ensure that all dispatched actions to the reducer function correctly maintain your state invariant.